# Simplifying nested map parsing

Tags: elixir

So I'm trying to parse this string into two lists of integers:

```
69 12 75 19 83 56 73 53 52 91 | 83 63 56 30 77 94 12 81 42 69 52 70  6 97 20 43 61 22 75 19 73 32 74 53 91
```

This works:

```
    [results_s, owned_s] =
      data_string
    |> String.split("|")
    |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ~r/\s+/))

    results = results_s
    |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)

    owned = owned_s
    |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
```

But  I was hoping to avoid the need for intermediate assignments. I've tried this:

```
    [results_s, owned_s] =
      data_string
    |> String.split("|")
    |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ~r/\s+/))
    |> Enum.map(&Enum.map(&1, &String.to_integer/1))
```

But get an error about nested captures.

And this:

```
    [results_s, owned_s] =
      data_string
    |> String.split("|")
    |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ~r/\s+/))
    |> Enum.map(fn (left, right ->
      {
        left |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1),
        right |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
      }
    end)
```

But get this error:

> Parsing: Card   1: 69 12 75 19 83 56 73 53 52 91 | 83 63 56 30 77 94
> 12 81 42 69 52 70  6 97 20 43 61 22 75 19 73 32 74 53 91
> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/1 in CardParser.parse_card/1
>
> ```
> The following arguments were given to anonymous fn/1 in CardParser.parse_card/1:
>
>     # 1
>     ["69", "12", "75", "19", "83", "56", "73", "53", "52", "91"]
> ```

Am I just overthinking this? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

One cannot use nested captures, but nested anonymous functions do still work.

```elixir
data_string
|> String.split("|")
|> Enum.map(fn e ->
  ~r/\d+/
  |> Regex.scan(e)
  |> List.flatten()
  |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1) 
end)

#⇒ [
#    [69, 12, 75, 19, 83, 56, 73, 53, 52, 91],
#    [83, 63, 56, 30, 77, 94, 12, 81, 42, 69, 52, 70, 6, 97, 20, 43, 61, 22, 75,
#     19, 73, 32, 74, 53, 91]
#  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Advent of Code 2023 Day 4](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/4).

You can see many alternatives on the [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/advent-of-code-2023-day-4/60132?u=adamu).

Here's [my method](https://git.adamu.jp/adam/AdventOfCode/src/branch/main/2023/day4.exs):

```elixir
line = "Card 1: 69 12 75 19 83 56 73 53 52 91 | 83 63 56 30 77 94 12 81 42 69 52 70  6 97 20 43 61 22 75 19 73 32 74 53 91"
[_card_id, winning, have] = String.split(line, [": ", " | "])

winning = winning |> String.split(" ", trim: true) |> MapSet.new()
have = have |> String.split(" ", trim: true) |> MapSet.new()
```

This produces:

```elixir
MapSet.new(["12", "19", "52", "53", "56", "69", "73", "75", "83", "91"])
```

and

```elixir
MapSet.new(["12", "19", "20", "22", "30", "32", "42", "43", "52", "53", "56",
"6", "61", "63", "69", "70", "73", "74", "75", "77", "81", "83", "91", "94",
"97"])
```

You don't actually need to parse the strings into integers for this puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I explicitly didn't ask for a solution to the puzzle, I asked for a solution to the specific issue I was facing at that point

Comment: Okay: Yes, you are over-thinking it. In this case it's much simpler to use intermediate assignments.

Comment: You have to duplicate something somewhere, because you need to keep the left and right separate. Either you have to duplicate the code, or call the same function on both sides. Alternatively if you know the index of `|`, you could parse the whole list once, then split it at the known index.

Comment: `line |> String.split(["|", " "], trim: true) |> Enum.split(10)`

Comment: Could you please modify your answer to explain that and then it's probably one I'll mark as accepted?